# ruby game with arrays and loops

Tags: ruby

Use the `river` variable that defines the river (see code below).
`-`: clear water.
`C`: crocodile.
The first five characters represent the first part of the river.
The second five characters represent the second part of the
river.
Each turn:
Check to see if the player is in the same position as a
crocodile.  If they are, `puts` `You were eaten.' and stop the program.` puts`the whole river.  Include a`P`where the player is. Ask the player if they want to go to left, right or neither. The player enters`left`,` right`or`neither`.  Make the player float down the river by one river part (one line of digits).  Move them to the left, the right, or keep them where they are. Print` You survived!` if the player makes it past all parts of the
river without hitting a crocodile.

To stop the game when the user is eaten or survives the
whole river, don't use `exit` to quit the program because this
will break the automated tests.  To exit a while loop early, use
the `break` keyword.

```
river = "--P--,--C--,CC-CC,CC-CC"
river1 = river.split(",")
x = 0
y = 2 

loop do
  puts river1
  puts "Type left, right or neither"
  input = gets.chomp
  if input == "left"
    river1[x][y] = "-"
    river1[(x += 1)][(y -= 1)] = "P"
  elsif input == "right"
    river1[x][y] = "-"
    river1[(x += 1)][(y -= 1)] = "P"
  elsif input == "neither"
    puts "You were eaten."
    break
  end
end
```

that's the first step which is working but i have no idea how to jump to another parts of the river in the loop. Im totally stuck

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Generally, homework questions don't receive a warm welcome here. If you do post homework questions you should go into detail about what you've done and what the *exact* problem is you're having. You should also [reformat your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) using the linked guide. I'd ask you to look at your own post; do you think that it is formatted correctly? Do you think that it is easy to read and that all the parts that should or should not be inline code are set? Many people will see your level of effort and not find it worthwhile to respond.

Comment: Tip: Instead of spreading things out and coming up with wonky variable names like `river1` when `river` itself is never used, consider: `river = '....'.split(',')` and just do it in one shot.

Comment: Another thing is Ruby's `case` is quite flexible and useful here, as in `case input` and then `when left` etc.

Comment: Thanks guys for the responses. @tadman good point about the variable. I'm aware it seems like I want someone else to do the job for me, cause the code isn't ready, but I'm just super new to all this so I appreciate all the tips.

Comment: It might help to A) shorten the input to just one letter so this is easier to test, B) display the state of the "river" each time input is processed, and C) start writing methods to make your life easier and de-duplicate code. For example, a first step is `def display_river(river)` and you then print it out. You could even include an `x,y` parameter which overlays the `P` character as necessary, saving you the hassle of merging it into the string itself.

Comment: Ruby is also fairly unique in that it *strongly* encourages classes even for seemingly trivial things. Like here, `class River` makes sense, and that split stuff goes in `def initialize` to prepare `@river` or `@board`, whatever you want to call the internal state. Think in terms of *manipulating data through methods*, not just bashing around with endless lines of Ruby. Let the methods describe what you're doing, like `river.move_player(2,3)` is pretty obvious. `river1[(x+=1)][(y+=1)]='P'` is not.

Comment: Things that help: Write your *high level* code first, *especially* in the context of a [unit test](https://rspec.info). This allows you to work out the overall logic without getting bogged down in the details. For example: `river = River.new`, then pick between `river.move_player(x,y)` or `river.move_player(:left)` or maybe there's some other structure like `game = Game.new(river)` and then it has control over the "player" part. See what feels best *before* getting stuck implementing.

Comment: Whenever you're writing code, always keep in mind: 1. What is the *responsibility* of this code? Is it getting too broad? 2. Does the name of the method or class communicate clearly what it does and doesn't do? 3. Am I following the "Principle of Least Surprise" as in the code does what it says on the tin and nothing more? 4. For any given method or class, is there an *obvious* way to test that it works correctly?